# Why does h2 changing of username and password dont work? Spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, h2, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I have  gradle spring boot app with h2 database in eclipse.When i try to login to console only default  username:`sa` and empty password  works even though i added config in application properties.Why?

My `application.properties` file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.data-username=test
spring.datasource.data-password=test
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

Console:

```
2020-06-27 22:49:21.425  INFO 13960 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    
: H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:testdb'
```

Dependencies in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
    exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
}

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jaxb:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.7.2'
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.7.2")

implementation('javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0')
implementation('javax.activation:activation:1.1')
implementation('org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.0')
}
```

Comment: Working with SB `2.4.1` and using `spring.datasource.data-XXX` arises an error of authentication when the app is started. The provided answer is correct. Use `spring.datasource.XXX` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It still works, because you are setting your username and password wrong.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#data-properties), property `spring.datasource.data-username` sets

> Username of the database to execute DML scripts (if different).

and `spring.datasource.data-password` sets

> Password of the database to execute DML scripts (if different).

You need to set `spring.datasource.username` and `spring.datasource.password`.

Your config file should look like:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```